# Как дефрагментировать даты в базе данных?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Здравствуйте. Имеется вот такая база данных: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9554b . Первая таблица отвечает за отображение номеров в гостинице, которые существуют, вторая - за существующие брони в гостинице. Я попытался её визуализировать:
 [image]
За такой порядок расстановки/распределения номеров отвечает sql код. Он берёт новые даты заезда и выезда, сравнивает их с таблицей main и проверяет свободный номер на эти даты. Первый попавшийся свободный номер он присвоит новой броне. Всё логично. От сюда и следует такой "хаотичное" распределение номеров. Вот, собственно, сам select запрос на выдачу номера.

```
SET @start = '2016-12-12'; -- Новая дата заезда
SET @end = '2016-12-20'; -- Новая дата выезда
SELECT a.nomer
FROM allnomer a
LEFT JOIN main m
  ON a.nomer = m.numbernomer
  AND DATEDIFF(m.datestart, @end) * DATEDIFF(m.dateend, @start) <= 0
WHERE a.type = 'lux' AND m.numbernomer IS NULL
LIMIT 1
```

Но есть у меня одна проблема. По сути, 12, 13, 14... 20 числа в гостинице жить никто не будет. Это свободные дни. Они образовались из-за распределения дат моим скриптом. Но если 11 числа придёт бронь на даты с 12 по 20, то скрипт её отвергнет (вернёт null), ибо даты заезда/выезда пересекаются. И это вполне ожидаемо, но хотелось бы решить эту проблему. Если перераспределить брони, то всё встанет на свои места, и номер с 12 по 20 число откроется.
[image]
Я не трогал еще действующие брони, я перемещал только будущие. 
Хотелось бы узнать, на сколько реальна эта затея с перераспределением/дефрагментацией, и как её воплотить в жизнь (может быть уже было что-то подобное, либо есть такой sql запрос для моего случая) ?

Comment: Да как два пальца. Бронь же фиксирует не конкретный номер, а какой-нибудь из номеров этого класса. Соответственно подумай и дополни запрос правильной сортировкой. А вот перераспределение делать - это не для SQL задача, над этим пусть клиент пыхтит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо за интересный вопрос.

Я попробовал реализовать алгоритм на MS SQL, и проигнорировал в большинстве мест фильтрацию по типу номера, надеюсь, у вас получится транслировать его в код для MySQL и добавить где надо условия на тип - должно быть несложно.

Основной смысл алгоритма - сбрасываем номера у всех броней, чье начало больше текущей даты, после чего заново присваиваем им номера по одному, распределяя их как можно плотнее к уже занятым датам.

```
declare @start date = '2016-12-12'; -- Новая дата заезда
declare @end date = '2016-12-20'; -- Новая дата выезда
declare @today date = '2016-12-11';

update  main 
set     numbernomer = null
where   datestart > @today;

declare @mainnumber int;

while exists (select * from main where numbernomer is null)
begin

    select top(1) @mainnumber = id
    from    main
    where   numbernomer is null
    order by datestart asc, datediff(day, datestart, dateend) desc;

    update m0
    set     numbernomer = m1.nomer
    from    main m0
            cross apply (SELECT top 1 a.nomer
                        FROM    allnomer a
                                LEFT JOIN main m
                                ON a.nomer = m.numbernomer
                                AND DATEDIFF(day, m.datestart, m0.dateend) * DATEDIFF(day, m.dateend, m0.datestart) <= 0
                                left join (select m2.numbernomer, max(m2.dateend) as dateend from main m2 group by m2.numbernomer) as m2
                                        on a.nomer = m2.numbernomer
                        WHERE a.type = 'lux' AND m.numbernomer IS NULL
                        order by datediff(day, m2.dateend, m0.datestart), a.nomer
                        ) as m1
    where   m0.id = @mainnumber;

end;

SELECT a.nomer
FROM allnomer a
LEFT JOIN main m
  ON a.nomer = m.numbernomer
  AND DATEDIFF(day, m.datestart, @end) * DATEDIFF(day, m.dateend, @start) <= 0
WHERE a.type = 'lux' AND m.numbernomer IS NULL;
```

Comment: Воу. Спасибо, конечно, но вы не натыкались на статью о том, как перевести ms sql на mysql? Уже час сижу и всё безуспешно...

Comment: 1) замените top 1 в select'е на limit 1 после селекта
2) уберите первый параметр "day" в функции Datediff
3) замените declare на set, убрав тип данных
4) возьмите кусок, который присоединяется через cross apply и поставьте его напрямую в присвоение значения.
Я бы все это сделал сам, но у меня базы под рукой нет, а SQLFiddle не работает почему то.

Comment: короче говоря, всё пришло к тому, что ваш вариант ответа самый верный. Я поставил ms sql, создал там бд и выполнил запрос. И о, чудо, всё сработало так, как нужно.  Но перевести мне его на мой язык так и не удалось. Что это единственно верный ответ есть и моя вина. Не совсем правильно я задал свой вопрос и понялы меня только вы.

Answer (score 4):

Оптимизирующий запрос из разряда магии переменных. Рассчитан на более правильную структуру базы данных, в которой, в таблице `main` нет поля `namenomer` так как оно дублируется из таблицы `allnomer`, чем нарушает [вторую нормальную форму](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0).
На вашей структуре БД запрос работает и его можно еще немного сократить, за счет того, что тип номера будет браться прямо из `main` (но я этого не рекомендую, а рекомендую нормализовать структуру БД).

```
set @today:=date('2016-12-11');
update main M
  join (
   select cid, nomer
     from (
       select A.nomer,
              @cstart:=if(@cnum=A.nomer,@cstart,A.start),
              @cnum:=A.nomer,
              @cid:=(select M.id
                       from main M,allnomer MT
                      where MT.nomer=M.numbernomer and MT.type='lux'
                        and M.datestart>@cstart
                        and find_in_set(M.id,@used)=0
                      order by datestart
                      limit 1
                    ) cid,
              @cstart:=(select dateend from main where id=@cid) dend,
              @used:=coalesce(concat(@used,',',@cid),@used)
         from (
          select A.nomer, A.start
            from (
              select A.nomer,
                     (select coalesce(min(dateend),@today-interval 1 day)
                        from main M
                       where datestart<=@today and M.numbernomer=A.nomer) start
                from allnomer A where type='lux'
            ) A,
            main M, allnomer MT
           where MT.nomer=M.numbernomer and MT.type='lux' and M.datestart>A.start
           order by A.start desc, A.nomer
         ) A,
         (select @cid:=0,@cnum:=0,@cstart:=NULL,@used:='') Y
     ) X where cid is not null
  ) U
  on M.id=U.cid
 set M.numbernomer=U.nomer
```

[Тест выбирающего подзапроса на sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9554b/6) (В первой колонке результата новый номер, который будет установлен записи резервов, после него все поля записи резерва, включая старый номер. В результате нет записей с nomer=302, т.к. в результате оптимизации этот номер оказывается свободным с 12 до 20 и на него не назначен ни один резерв).

Принцип работы: Самый глубокий подзапрос получает список всех номеров с последней датой активного на сегодня (переменная `@today`) резерва. Если в данный момент номер свободен, то последней занятой датой считается вчерашний день. К каждому номеру приклеиваются все существующие резервы с более поздними датами со всех номеров данного типа. Но по факту их данные в работе не используются, они нужны только для порождения заведомо достаточного для эмуляции рекурсии количества записей. Полученные записи сортируются в обратном порядке по дате окончания текущего резерва. Т.е. первым обрабатываемым номером окажется 304, т.к. его текущий резерв оканчивается 13 числа.

Для каждой записи пытаемся найти такую запись резерва, которая в запросе ранее еще не встречалась (ее нет в переменной `@used`) и у которой дата начала наиболее близка к текущей обрабатываемой дате. Если запись найдена (`@cid` НЕ NULL), то в качестве следующей рабочей даты берем ее дату окончания. Таким образом в следующей записи будет найдена одна запись с началом наиболее близким к текущей. Когда обработка текущего номера заканчивается (новый номер не равен старому `@cnum`) рабочая дата сбрасывается в дату освобождения нового номера и мы ищем следующую цепочку резервов.

P.S. Хранимой процедурой конечно можно сделать по проще и более понятно, с сохранением общего принципа. Но мне интересно делать единым запросом, особенно в такой ситуации, когда это кажется невозможным.

Comment: Спасибо за решение, но в нём я нашел ошибку. Если указать другую дату моложе 10, то даты дефрагментируются не верно. Я создал новый вопрос, где приложил скрины происходящего http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604503/Почему-при-другой-дате-даты-дефрагментируются-неверно

Answer (score 1):

Структуры и наполнение - из инит-поста на sqlfiddle.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pack()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE d_start DATE;
    DECLARE d_end DATE;
    DECLARE num varchar(7);
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT datestart, dateend FROM main ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE appts(nomer varchar (7), free_from DATE) ENGINE = Memory;
    INSERT INTO appts(nomer, free_from) SELECT nomer, 0 FROM allnomer;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE shedule(nomer varchar (7), datestart DATE, dateend DATE) ENGINE = Memory;
    OPEN cur;
read_loop:
    LOOP    
        FETCH cur INTO d_start, d_end;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF; 
        SELECT a.nomer INTO num 
            FROM appts a
            WHERE a.free_from < d_start 
            ORDER BY 1 
            LIMIT 1;    
        INSERT INTO shedule 
            SELECT num, d_start, d_end;
        UPDATE appts a
            SET a.free_from = d_end
            WHERE a.nomer = num;
    END LOOP read_loop;
    CLOSE cur;
    SELECT nomer, datestart, dateend 
        FROM shedule
        ORDER BY 1, 2;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE shedule;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE appts;
END;
```