# Почему при другой дате даты дефрагментируются неверно

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Я уже задавал вопрос: [Как дефрагментировать даты в базе данных?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600853/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) и там было предложено решение, но, как оказалось, в этом решении есть ошибка. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот так выглядит база первоначально. Если применить вот этот код:

```
    set @today:=date('2016-12-11');
update main M
  join (
   select cid, nomer
     from (
       select A.nomer,
              @cstart:=if(@cnum=A.nomer,@cstart,A.start),
              @cnum:=A.nomer,
              @cid:=(select M.id
                       from main M,allnomer MT
                      where MT.nomer=M.numbernomer and MT.type='lux'
                        and M.datestart>@cstart
                        and find_in_set(M.id,@used)=0
                      order by datestart
                      limit 1
                    ) cid,
              @cstart:=(select dateend from main where id=@cid) dend,
              @used:=coalesce(concat(@used,',',@cid),@used)
         from (
          select A.nomer, A.start
            from (
              select A.nomer,
                     (select coalesce(min(dateend),@today-interval 1 day)
                        from main M
                       where datestart<=@today and M.numbernomer=A.nomer) start
                from allnomer A where type='lux'
            ) A,
            main M, allnomer MT
           where MT.nomer=M.numbernomer and MT.type='lux' and M.datestart>A.start
           order by A.start desc, A.nomer
         ) A,
         (select @cid:=0,@cnum:=0,@cstart:=NULL,@used:='') Y
     ) X where cid is not null
  ) U
  on M.id=U.cid
 set M.numbernomer=U.nomer
```

То база будет выглядеть так: (так она должна выглядеть после дефрагментации)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если изменить set @today:=date('2016-12-11'); на set @today:=date('2016-12-05'); (или любая дата моложе 10), то дефрагментация будет вот такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: Когда все номера еще свободны алгоритм рассматривает только один вариант, начиная заполнение с минимального номера. Для абсолютно правильной дефрагментации ни один алгоритм подбирающий первую попавшуюся ближайшую бронь не годится. Необходимо рассмотреть все возможные варианты перестановок броней. Для этого нужна рекурсия, а MySQL чуть ли ни единственная БД, не поддерживающая рекурсивные запросы. А эмуляция рекурсии ради нескольких броней породит миллионы строк и работать будет очень медленно.

Comment: хотя ради прикола попробуйте добавить в получение очередной брони в цепочке (перед limit 1) в сортировку длину брони, что бы первой брала самую длинную, может поможет. но все равно наверняка найдутся такие комбинации, которые будут оптимизироваться не эффективно

Comment: @Mike самое смешное, что первые даты он не трогает. Он же мог кинуть 10-11 наверх. А по поводу сортировки. Должно быть что-то типа order dateend - datestart ?

Comment: У вас в предыдущем вопросе был ваш пример запроса, где использовалась функция `datediff()` как раз возвращающая разницу двух дат. А чего он куда кинет собственно сортировка и решает. Там сейчас стоит только по дате начала, предсказать какую именно запись с одинаковыми датами начала он возьмет невозможно

Comment: @Mike не вышло. стало еще хуже

Comment: А вы по двум полям сортировали, по дате начала и по длине. И попробовали длину и по убыванию и по возрастанию (а то как нибудь не так diff напишите, отрицательные значения выдаст ...)

Comment: да, разные варианты попробовал - всё фигня. а по поводу отрицательного числа, разве "<= 0" нельзя использовать в sort?

Comment: А вам не кажется, что решение, результат которого зависит от параметра, отсутствующего в исходной задаче, по определению не может быть верным?

Comment: @Akina , кажется...