# Нетривиальная сортировка

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sqlite3

Есть таблица, пусть для "синтетического" примера - просто таблица целых чисел. Числа могут повторяться и не могут принимать значение NULL. Нужно вывести сортированный список по возрастанию "дистанции".

**Определение "дистанции"**

`Dij =  ABS(ABS(Ti)-ABS(Tj))`

Где:

- `Dij` - дистанция между i-м и j-м элементом
- `Ti,Tj` - i-й и j-й элементы таблицы

**Правила сортировки**

- `Dij<Djk`
- Если на очередной итерации сортировки на место очередной пары претендуют несколько пар (`Dij==Djk`), выбирается та пара, у которой есть число - наименьшее из всех чисел из данных пар
- по возможности `Ti` < `Tj`

**Поправка**

"Возрастание дистанции" - скорее всего не совсем верная формулировка. Потому как выбор очередной пары зависит от предыдущей. Иными словами - второй элемент предыдущей пары на очередной итерации становится первым в текущей. Поэтому "дистанции" могут "плясать". Типа 2-3-10-1-2-2-7-3...

**Для теста**

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
  Digit INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Test (Digit)
VALUES (17),(16),(9),(8),(7),(3),(0),(-5),(-10),(-17);
```

Нужный порядок сортировки:

```
-17
17
16
-10
9
8
7
-5
3
0
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51307/discussion-on-question-by-majestio--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite, postgesql:

```
WITH RECURSIVE Q(Digit,ids,Level) as(
  select * from (
    select a.Digit,','||a.rowid ids,0 as Level
      from Test a, Test b
     where a.rowid!=b.rowid
     order by abs(abs(a.Digit)-abs(b.Digit)),a.Digit
     limit 1
  ) A
  union all
  select a.Digit,ids||','||a.rowid,Level+1
    from Q, Test a
   where a.rowid in(
          select b.rowid from Test b,(select Q.digit as d) C
           where Q.ids||',' not like '%,'||b.rowid||',%'
           order by abs(abs(b.Digit)-abs(C.d)),b.Digit
           limit 1
         )

)
select Digit from Q order by Level
```

"странный" подзапрос `(select Q.digit as d)` пришлось ввести специально для SQLite, потому как он в фразе `order by` подзапроса в упор не хочет видеть поля таблицы Q. Для posgresql это не требуется и `Q.Digit` можно указать прямо в `order by`.

На MySQL решать это ни имею ни малейшего желания, ибо рекурсивных запросов там нет. Хотя в принципе рекурсия может быть эмулирована размножением записей и накапливанием "вышедших" номеров в переменных, примерно как в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600853/).

Comment: Майк, просто огромное спасибо!!! Буду разбираться и учиться))